# usando Ajax para buscar estado - cidade

Tags: ajax, combobox

Preciso criar uma conbobox de estado e de cidades. De acordo com o estado selecionado, são exibidas as cidades correspondentes.

```
<select name="estados" id="estados">
<option value="0">Selecione o estado</option>
    <?php
       $result = mysql_query("select distinct loc_uf from local ORDER BY loc_uf ASC");
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) )
       {
            echo "<option value='".$row['id_pais']."'>".$row['loc_uf']."</option>";
       }
    ?>
```

```
<select name="cidades" id="cidades">
<option value="">Selecione a cidade</option>
      //como usar ajax e buscar cidade de acordo com estado selecionado??
</select>
```

tabela

nome: 
     local

campos:

```
id_local
loc_cidade
loc_uf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente, vamos ao código da página onde os droplists se encontram:

Código do droplist de estados

```
<select name="estados" id="estados">
    <option value="0">Selecione o estado</option>
    <?php
       $result = mysql_query("select distinct loc_uf from local ORDER BY loc_uf ASC");
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) )
       {
            echo "<option value='".$row['loc_uf']."'>".$row['loc_uf']."</option>";
       }
    ?>
</select>
```

Nesta mesma página, o código do droplist de cidades:

```
<select name="cidades" id="cidades">
    <font id="font_cidades"></font>
</select>
```

Ainda nesta página, o código para buscar as cidades com AJAX. Para esta página, utilizei também JQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#estados').change(
        function() {
            var estado = $('#estado').val(); //Pegando o id do estado
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",  
                url: "AJAX_buscaCidades.php?estado="+estado,
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#font_cidades').html(data); //Se obtivermos sucesso na busca dos dados, atribuímos os dados para o select
                }
            });
        }
    );

</script>
```

E por fim, vamos ao arquivo AJAX_buscaCidades.php, que irá buscar as cidades quando for fornecido o id do estado.

```
<?php

    $sqlQuery = "select distinct loc_cidade from local WHERE loc_uf = " . $_GET['estado'] . " ORDER BY loc_cidade ASC";

    $result = mysql_query();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<option value='".$row['loc_cidade']."'>".$row['loc_cidade']."</option>";
    }

?>
```

Algumas considerações:

- O código ainda está 'cru', precisa fazer alterações nas consultas, nos campos, etc.
- Sugiro utilizar MYSQLI para fazer as consultas com mais segurança.

Bom proveito!

Comment: Não está dando erro dessa forma, mas ao selecionar o estado nao aparece nada na combobox cidades. As consultas estão corretas e importei dentro do <head> o <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>.

Comment: @PHPdeveloper, sugiro incluir os javascripts no footer e não no header. talvez seja isso

Comment: Nada ainda... como posso testar se o $_GET['estado'] está capturando o estado selecionado e não está vindo em branco?